# How would you minimize the following?

Tags: matrices, optimization, convex-analysis

$\min \rho||x||_1 + \left<\lambda,x\right>$ with respect to $x$

I'm not too sure what to do with this problem, I considered $\left<\lambda,x\right>=\frac{1}{2}\left(||x+\lambda||_2^2-||x||_2^2-||\lambda||_2\right)$. Then I would have to minimize $\rho||x||_1+\frac{1}{2}\left(||x+\lambda||_2^2-||x||_2^2\right)$, but I don't really know how to proceed from here.

Comment: There should be a factor of $2$ or $1/2$ in your inner product identity.

Comment: You need something like $\|\lambda\|_\infty \le \rho$ for this to have a finite solution. In this case a solution is $x=0$.

Comment: @theoBendit thanks! changed it

Comment: @copper.hat how did you get that? thanks.

Comment: I added an answer and a very informal explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that we can write the cost as
$f(x)=\sum_k (\rho + \lambda_k \operatorname{sgn} x_k )|x_k|$.

Suppose $\rho < \|\lambda\|_\infty$. Let $l$ be an index such that $\|\lambda\|_\infty =|\lambda_l| $ and choose $x_k = 0$ except for $x_l = -t \operatorname{sgn} \lambda_l$ and we get $f(x) = t(\rho - |\lambda_l| )|\lambda_l|$ and hence the problem is unbounded below.

If $\rho \ge \|\lambda\|_\infty$, we see that $f(x) \ge 0$ and hence $x=0$ is a minimiser.

**Note**: You asked how did I come up with this. Very informally, as follows:

$\inf_x \rho \|x\|_1 + \lambda^T x = \inf_x \sup_{\|y\|_\infty \le 1} (\rho y+\lambda)^T x= \sup_{\|y\|_\infty \le 1} \inf_x (\rho y+\lambda)^T x$.

For this we see (informally) that if $\rho y+\lambda \neq 0$ then it is unbounded below, so we need $\rho y+\lambda = 0$ and for this to happen I need ${1 \over \rho} \|\lambda\|_\infty \le 1$, and when this
is true the $\inf$ is zero.